# Using apache exec on interactive command mode

Tags: java, terminal, apache-commons-exec

What I need to do is enter interactive mode of an application, and then start sending commands to it. The application is graphicsmagick. batch mode puts you in a state similar to how mysql works, where you can then send commands without the name of the application prefixing the command. Here is what I have done:

```
   public Executor startBatchMode( OutputStream input )  {

            Executor executor = new DefaultExecutor();

            CommandLine cmdLine = new CommandLine( cmdPath );    
            cmdLine.addArgument( "batch" );

            DefaultExecuteResultHandler resultHandler = new DefaultExecuteResultHandler();

      //  AutoFlushingPumpStreamHandler: https://gist.github.com/martypitt/4653381       
     //   AutoFlushingPumpStreamHandler streamHandler = new AutoFlushingPumpStreamHandler( System.out );

            PumpStreamHandler streamHandler = new PumpStreamHandler( System.out );
            streamHandler.setProcessInputStream(input  );
            executor.setStreamHandler( streamHandler );

            try {
                executor.execute( cmdLine, resultHandler );
                streamHandler.start();

            } catch ( IOException e ) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return executor;
        }

        public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException {
            ExecWrapper exec = new ExecWrapper( "/usr/local/bin/gm" );
            OutputStream stream = new PipedOutputStream(  );
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(stream);
            Executor executor = exec.startBatchMode( stream );
            for(int i=0;i<5;i++)   {
                writer.write( "convert /Users/latu/Desktop/400.jpg /Users/latu/Desktop/"+i+".png\n" );
                writer.flush();     
            }

             writer.close();
```

For the output, the application enters the batch mode, and then terminates. When used from terminal it will enter batch mode and then wait for a command from user until EOF character. I have tried adding commands to the writer before calling startBatchMode() but made no difference. Also tried moving things around quite a lot, but the outcome is always the same.

Any suggestions as to how I can make this work?

**Update**

Turns out this is very straight forward using Java runtime, and works like this:

```
   private void runExec() throws IOException {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "/usr/local/bin/gm batch" );

        OutputStream stdin = process.getOutputStream();

        for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
            String line = "convert /Users/latu/Desktop/400.jpg /Users/latu/Desktop/" + i + ".png" + "\n";
            stdin.write( line.getBytes() );
            stdin.flush();
        }
    }
```

Although I am hoping to stay with exec as it has some nice features which ideally I wouldn't need to reimplement.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the streams. I needed to create a PipedOutputStream and pass it to a PipedInputStream. Then pass the PipedInputStream to my StreamHandler constructor. After that anything written on PipedOutputStream was executed as expected.